# Php - How to reorder a date

Tags: php, date

I have a date which is formatted simply as 19830210 (YYYYDDMM).

How would I reorder it to 02101983 (DDMMYYYY) using php?

I simply want to rearrange the digits in the date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), do:

```
$date = "19830210";
$newFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ydm', $date);
echo $newFormat->format('dmY'); //will give you 02101983
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo $output=date('dmY',strtotime('02101983'));
```

For future use with date format use below link for reference 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

use **substr()** function:

```
<?php
$date1 = 'YYYYDDMM';
$date2 = substr($date1 , 4 , 4).substr($date1 , 0 , 4);
echo $date2;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='19830210'; //(YYYYDDMM).
echo $str."<br/>";
$yy=substr($str,0,4);
$mm=substr($str,4,2);
$dd=substr($str,6,2);
$reorder=$dd.$mm.$yy;
echo $reorder;   //(DDMMYYYY).
```